# When should we use HttpMultipartMode as 'STRICT'?

Tags: java, spring-boot, httpclient, multipartform-data

I am using org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder for sending the multipart form data using apache HttpClient in a SpringBoot Application.

Recently, I saw  a usecase , where one of the request was giving response as

```
415 Unsupported Media Type
```

While trying to debug the issue, I changed the MultipartEntityBuilder object's HttpMultipartMode from **BrowserCompatible to Strict** . And it started giving the expected response 200.

I tried to search a lot but still not able to completely understand what impact does changing the HttpMultipartMode makes.
Can someone please help me to understand this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the source code for more information:

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.7/org/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipartMode.html

Strict seems to follow the RFC standards, BrowerCompatible not

When I have issues like these I usually make sure to test my request outside of Spring (i.e. Postman or similar) to understand the differences headers make (usually different headers will be the problem in some way)

Comment: Thanks @breakline for the response.. One more doubt here, how do we know from postman in which mode it is getting sent. As that api was getting passed from postman with same headers and other configurations.

Comment: Postman adds its own headers too automatically (you can uncheck this in the headers section). If all the headers are the same and the data is the same etc. you'll have to have the same end result (unless there is some other issue like with proxies). Also you can try using curl but thats not as steamlined as postman. I have had similar issues which were caused by extra headers added from Postman (in my case my request worked in postman but not in an Android app)

Answer (score 0):

Curious to know other side code, While implementing API (rest service), what changes make this difference. To make API strict mode what particular changes I have to make in code.